# Get values of all options in a mulitselect

Tags: jquery

I have a multiselect from which I need to get the value property of all of the options - not just the selected ones - using jQuery.

I tried

```
$('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse').each(function (index) {
    console.log('index: ' + index + ', value: ' + $(this).val())
});
```

but that didn't work (I figured it wouldn't, but I'm not sure what to try).

Ideally, I need to build a comma-separated list of the values, which are just numbers (database ids of the option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
$(function(){
 var arr = [];
 $('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse').children().each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).val());
 });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5XhL2/

Comment: This answer gave me the comma-separated list I needed, too. Thanks, Jeevan.

Answer (score 4):

You're looping through each of the objects with that ID, which there will probably just be the one.

Instead, you need to loop through the `option` tags underneath it:

```
$('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse option').each(function(idx) {
    // etc.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = $('multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse option').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JzVZ7/1/)**

This will give you an array of all values.

### OR

#### *Using the `attr()` callback:*

```
var values = [];
$('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse option').attr('value', function() {
   values.push(this.value);  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JzVZ7/3/)**

Comment: What is that `attr('value')` supposed to do there? The way you used it `.each` would've done the job better.

Answer (score 1):

You're only looping over the one `#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse` element currently. You will either have to use `#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse option` as a selector or use the [`.children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) before looping:

```
$('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse').children().each(function(i) {
    console.log("index: "+i, "value: "+this.value);
});
```

> I need to build a comma-separated list of the values

Then use the following:

```
var numbers = $.map($('#multiSelectAssignedGoTosForCourse').children(), function() {
    return this.value;
}).join(",");
```

Comment: Dangit - I just figured it out but didn't get back here to post my answer before someone else did! Thanks!